# Improving a script to count repetition in a DNA string

Tags: python

Thanks to this community I've found a script that enables me to count through a string (in this case a DNA sequence) the number of repeated nucleotide everytime they are present in the sequence. Here's the script

```
s = input('Your sequence here:')

from itertools import groupby

groups = groupby(s)
result = [(label, sum(1 for _ in group)) for label, group in groups]
print (result)
```

the result from this is like this:

```
Your sequence here:AATAACACACATCGCTCACCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCNCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCTCCCTCCCTCGCCCTCTCCTCAGAGA
[('A', 2), ('T', 1), ('A', 2), ('C', 1), ('A', 1), ('C', 1), ('A', 1), ('C', 1), ('A', 1), ('T', 1), ('C', 1), ('G', 1), ('C', 1), ('T', 1), ('C', 1), ('A', 1), ('C', 50), ('N', 1), ('C', 22), ('T', 1), ('C', 3), ('T', 1), ('C', 3), ('T', 1), ('C', 1), ('G', 1), ('C', 3), ('T', 1), ('C', 1), ('T', 1), ('C', 2), ('T', 1), ('C', 1), ('A', 1), ('G', 1), ('A', 1), ('G', 1), ('A', 1)]
```

now, how would you improve it to show only those big repetitions of Cs? like that C, 50 or C,22?

Comment: How would _you_ do it? It's really not difficult

Comment: Just use logic. find all tuples with c using loop and if statement. Then print only those larger than threshold in another if statement but within the same loop

Comment: @lllrnr101 note that question is about consecutive items, not all together

Comment: Thanks! Did not notice that!

Comment: @ForceBru I'm not an expert in programming, I'm learning and taking good advices here in the community.

Answer (score 2):

You might use `list`-comprehension for example

```
data = [('A', 2), ('T', 1), ('A', 2), ('C', 1), ('A', 1), ('C', 1), ('A', 1), ('C', 1), ('A', 1), ('T', 1), ('C', 1), ('G', 1), ('C', 1), ('T', 1), ('C', 1), ('A', 1), ('C', 50), ('N', 1), ('C', 22), ('T', 1), ('C', 3), ('T', 1), ('C', 3), ('T', 1), ('C', 1), ('G', 1), ('C', 3), ('T', 1), ('C', 1), ('T', 1), ('C', 2), ('T', 1), ('C', 1), ('A', 1), ('G', 1), ('A', 1), ('G', 1), ('A', 1)]
big = [i for i in data if i[1]>=20]
print(big)
```

output

```
[('C', 50), ('C', 22)]
```

Comment: you might need to add "and i[0] == 'C'"

Comment: If you want to ensure you always get only the 'C' values for changing arrays

Comment: I am not sure what OP wants. They mention 'only those big repetitions of Cs?' Do they want only 'C' or any big repetition and C was mentioned just to illustrate because that sequence has only C in huge repetitions. @AlessioCantara

Comment: Daweo Thanks a lot for the answer!
@lllrnr101 Yep C was just an example in this particular sequence. I have some with lots of Gs and others with Ts and so on. So I'm just trying to understand how to write a general script that is able to calculate highly repeated part of the sequences I input.